# Unkown partitions after cloning HDD

Tags: partitioning, ssd, clone

I cloned my 500 GB traditional HDD to a new 512 GB SSD yesterday using `ddrescue` from a Ubuntu live CD. First, I wrote the whole HDD in a file on another external hard disk and then used this file to write it on my new SSD. I followed several tutorials on the web how to do it. The cloning resulted in no errors. Furthermore, mounting the file under Ubuntu succeeded without any problems.

However, after writing this image file on my new SSD all partitions are unknown and I cannot mount the hard disk. See the next screenshot for more information:

SSD after cloning:
[image: disks-screenshot]

I re-tried this using `dd ... conv=sync,noerror`. However, I get the same problem with the unknown partitions on the SSD.

I there anything I did wrong? Do I have to repair the partitions?

Successfully mounted image file:
[image: disks-screenshot]

Comment: What was the exact command you used?

Comment: Yes. I think I used bs=32k for the `dd` command, but I am not sure anymore. The `ddrescue` command was used without any additional flags.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Here are the exact commands: `dd bs=32k if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb conv=sync,noerror (sda = HDD, sdb = SDD)` and `ddrescue /dev/sda /media/.../hdd.img` and after that `ddrescue /media../hdd.img /dev/sdc` (in this case the image was written to an external hard disk and sdc = SSD).

Comment: So you cloned the original HDD to another drive, then to an image file, then the image file to a third drive?  Is the original drive no longer connected to the system?  Because your image only shows three total drives and only one of them is 512 gb.

Comment: Exactly, the first time I used `ddrescue` to write an image file from my original HDD (500 GB) to an external third HDD (1 TB). This image was then used to write it on the new SSD (512 GB). The second time I omitted the intermediary step and used `dd` to directly copy the original HDD on the new SSD. Both time resulted in the same problem I described above. The screenshots are taken from another computer because of convenience reasons.

Comment: Why didn't you use `ddrescue` to write the image file back?  Did you try that in the mean time? If not use onbe of the two: or `dd` or `ddrescue`.  Looks like you're trying to mix 2 tutorials into one...

Comment: I might not have made it clear: I used `ddrescue` to copy AND to write for the first try. This resulted in the same unknown partitioning problem I have described above. Since this didn't work out I used `dd` to directly copy (i.e., read and write at the same time). So I did not mix anything up. I used both methods consecutively.